# loop input and listbox

Tags: vba

im studying vba and i need to write a code that the users enters the sales of the week "Each day individualy" and show it in an listbox im using this as an last resource i dont need the entire code i just need to known how i can make it happen

Comment: May be you can tell us what you have tried so far? It's difficult to help you in such a broad question. Is it for Ms-Excel? Is it for a standalone app? Here you have a good example of some aproaches you can use in a similar sales problem, take a look: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/sales-calculator.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [inputbox](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-inputbox/) to get the value from the user. Then you can populate and display the [listbox](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-useform-listbox-control-guide). These links should help you achieve what you want. If you have any specific issues after that then post up the code you have tried with the exact error you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dias() As String{"Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes","Miercoles", "Jueves","Viernes","Sabado"}
Dim ventas As Double
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MakeArray()
End Sub
Private Sub MakeArray()
    For ventas = 0 To 6
        InputBox("Escriba las ventas finales de los dias correspondientes")
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For total = 0 To 6 Step 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dias + ventas)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

the variables are in spanish but this is what im trying to do

Comment: If this isn't a solution to your question (I'm assuming this as you stated *this is what I'm trying to do*) you should move this information to your question by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62163060/edit) and delete this as an answer.